# Faster way to insert into an unordered map

Tags: c++

I have an unordered map, exactly like:

```
std::unordered_map < std::string, std::vector<std::string> > m_unordered_map;
```

While inserting values into it, which of the following would be faster and why?

Approach 1 (Skeleton):

```
std:string key = "key";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  std::string value = std::to_string(i); // Value would be acually an big string.
  m_unordered_map[key].push_back(value1);
}
```

Approach 2 (Skeleton)

```
std:string key = "key";
std::vector<std::string> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  std::string value = std::to_string(i); // Value would be acually an big string.
  vec.insert(value);
}
m_unordered_map.insert({key, vec});
```

Or is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: why don't you time it for your particular use case and see which is faster?

Comment: @SamerTufail, I found approach 2 as faster in my environment. Having said that, to test runtime, I do not have dedicated machine which can confirm me the right runtime numbers. Also, intention is to get familiar with other approaches as well. Make sense?

Comment: @SamerTufail Presumably because timing such things reliably and in a way that’s representative of real data is actually quite hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know the key in advance for a batch of things, then the second of the versions you have is significantly better, as it avoids doing a map lookup on *every iteration*.

You may further improve it by *moving* instead of *copying* the string and vectors. e.g.

```
std::string key = "key";
std::vector<std::string> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    vec.emplace_back(std::to_string(i));
}
m_unordered_map.emplace(key, std::move(vec));
```

In general:

- Accessing an `unordered_map` is still fairly slow, **especially** with keys like `std::string`. For a "hit" it costs you a O(n) hash on the keys length, and a O(n) string comparison. Not just O(1) for the hash table itself. If you can access it just once, maybe keep an iterator/reference that will be faster (check the iterator invalidation rules. `insert` may invalidate other iterators in an `unordered_map`, so be careful, but it won't invalidate references to values). If you can replace the string entirely with say an integer ID that will also normally be faster.
- Avoid copying objects like maps, strings, and vectors. When possible move them. As well as the cost of copying the data, copying containers can cause a lot of comparatively expensive memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Amelioration of your 2 approaches:

Approach 1(Skeleton):

```
std:string key = "key";
auto& vec = m_unordered_map[key];
vec.reserve(n);
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(std::to_string(i));
}
```

Approach 2(Skeleton)

```
std:string key = "key";
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.reserve(n);
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(std::to_string(i));
}
m_unordered_map[key] = std::move(vec));
```

So

- do only one lookup
- Use move instead of copy.

On my side, I would create a method to build the vector, something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> create_iota_strings(std::size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.reserve(n);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(std::to_string(i));
    }
    return vec;
}
```

and then simply

```
m_unordered_map[key] = create_iota_strings(n);
```

`insert`/`emplace` might be more appropriate than `operator[]` if you know key doesn't already exist.
If key might exist `try_emplace` would be the solution to avoid to construct the empty vector (when key doesn't exist).